# Android/Gradle: Add an asset after the compile phase

Tags: android, gradle

I have a task that generates a metadata file based off the compiled classes in an Android Gradle build.  I can get it to run by executing it after the compile task:

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    def variantName = variant.name.capitalize()
    def compileSourcesTaskName = "compile${variantName}Sources"
    def compileSourcesTask = project.tasks.findByName(compileSourcesTaskName)
    compileSourcesTask.finalizedBy "myTaskThatGeneratesAssets"
}
```

Unfortunately, Android has already processed the assets at this point.  The new file won't get included in the assembled APK.

An answer to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24435209/180891) suggests calling `aapt add` to add the file to the APK before alignment/signing.  This seems like it could work, but the post doesn't go into implementation details.  The code to call `aapt` in [the Android Gradle plugin](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/build/+/7eff27462d5989acf22839575ff0a8978e3369b5/builder/src/main/java/com/android/builder/AndroidBuilder.java#228) looks fairly complicated for a build script, and I'm not sure how to get access to the `IAndroidTarget` it references.

I'd appreciate suggestions on how to implement this, or any other solutions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, here's what I ended up with.  It makes two assumptions that may break on later versions of the android gradle plugin (I'm using 1.3.0):

1. The path to the platform tools is `${android.getSdkDirectory().getAbsolutePath()}/build-tools/${android.buildToolsVersion}/`
2. The path to the intermediate (resources) APK is `${buildDir}/intermediates/res/resources-${variant.baseName}.ap_`

So long as those are true, this should generate a task to add the new asset file using `aapt` after the resources APK has already been built:

```
def overlayDir = ... // path to a resources overlay directory that contains "assets/my.json"
def addMyAssetTaskName = "add${variantName}MyAsset"
task "${addMyAssetTaskName}" (type: Exec) {
    dependsOn myTaskThatGeneratesAssets
    workingDir overlayDir
    def aaptCommand = "${android.getSdkDirectory().getAbsolutePath()}/build-tools/${android.buildToolsVersion}/aapt"
    def apkPath = "${buildDir}/intermediates/res/resources-${variant.baseName}.ap_"
    commandLine aaptCommand, 'add', apkPath, "assets/my.json"
}
```

Then I use `finalizedBy` like in the question above to `addMyAssetTaskName`.